# Trying to move a folder(s) if they exist

Tags: powershell

I'm not getting the if/else state to work. I'm trying to move a folder or folders that starts with numbers 0-9. If the folders are there the folders will be moved. But im trying to make an else statement if they dont exists. Here is my script:

```
$Source = "\\Server\share"
$Destination = "\\Server\Archive"
$Dir = Get-ChildItem $Source | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\d"}

if (!(Test-Path $Source | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\d"}))
{
   Move-Item $Dir -Destination $Destination
}
else
{
Write-Host "No folder to backup"
}
```

Anyone have any good suggestion how I should solve this or use a different method?

Comment: _starts with letters 0-9_ care to update that part of the sentence? Starts with numbers 0-9 perhaps?

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you are trying to move. If `Get-ChildItem` returns anything that means they exist. Also if they need to start with numbers you should use `^\d`. If you want to see if $dir contains anything then `if($dir){}` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going out on a limb my guess would be that you want to check if `$Source` contains one or more subfolder(s) whose name starts with a digit, and move those that exist to `$Destination`. If that assumption is correct I'd suggest to do the following:

```
$Source      = '\\Server\share'
$Destination = '\\Server\Archive'

$Dir = Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^\d'}

if ($Dir) {
  $Dir | Move-Item -Destination $Destination
} else {
  Write-Host 'No folder to backup'
}
```